# stacking time series graph python

Tags: python, stacked-chart

I want to stack the time series of SST and NickSST on 1 plot. When I try to do it simply, I get this error:

`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (31,) and (0,).`

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class buoy(object):
    def __init__(self, bID):
        self.buoyID = bID
        self.dateTime = []
        self.SST = []
        self.NickSST = []

    def plotSST(self, stID):
        plotName = stID + "-" + self.buoyID
        self.fig1 = plt.figure()
        plt.ion()
        self.axis1 = self.fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.axis1.plot(self.dateTime, self.SST)
        self.axis1.plot(self.dateTime, self.NickSST)
        self.axis1.set_title("Time Series for" + "" + plotName)
        self.axis1.set_xlabel("Date/Time (UTC)")
        self.axis1.set_ylabel("SST (degrees C)")
        self.fig1.savefig(plotName + ".png")
        plt.show(self.fig1)

class storm(object):
    def __init__(self, stID):
        self.stormID = stID
        self.buoyList = []
```

Please tell me how I am going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no data in either `self.SST` or `self.NickSST`.

Matplotlib expects the same number of values in both lists when you call `plot(x, y)`

The error is telling you that your X axis has 31 values and nothing in your Y.
Try printing the length of each array:

```
print(len(self.dataTime), len(self.SST), len(self.NickSST))
```